# Resolving shift/reduce error

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

```
expr    : expr relOps expr
        | expr logOps expr
        | OPENP expr CLOSEP
        | term addOps factor
        | term
        ;

term    : factor mulOps term
        | factor
        ;

factor  : IDENTIFIER
        | CONSTANT
        ;

addOps  : ADD
        | MINUS
        ;

mulOps  : MUL
        | DIV
        | MOD
        ;

relOps  : LT
        | EQ
        | GT
        ;

logOps  : AND
        | OR
        | NOT
        ;
```

This is part of my grammar. When I compile, and look at y.output, I get 12 shift/reduce errors. The errors come from expr relOps expr and expr logOps expr, with 1 error for each logOp and relOp.

I understand the ambiguity here, IE, the statement a > b > c can be read as (a > b) > c and a > (b > c). I've tried everything I can think of to assign the correct precedence to resolve this. However, I cannot.

Can anyone resolve this or point me towards a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Not related to your problem, but are you probably don't want to define `NOT` as a binary operator, `expr NOT expr` doesn't really make sense. You'll want a separate rule for unary operators for that. Anyway, regarding your problem: Can you post the precedence annotations that you've tried?

Comment: Yes. Your link led me to a solution, as well as a good understanding of what the issue was. Thank you! also, @sepp2k, you are correct! I will make that adjustment